# Is WHERE clause supposed to update a table in Posgresql, and if so, how can I have a where clause that does not write to it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

Sorry if this isn't a good question, I'm new to SQL and not sure what exactly I should be googling

So I have a table `tmp`

| country | admin_name | capital |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tokyo | Japan | primary |

And another one `capital_type`

| type | capital_type_id |
| --- | --- |
| primary | 1 |

I want to add a column `capital_type_id` to the table `tmp`, so I did

```
ALTER TABLE TMP ADD COLUMN capital_type_id int;

UPDATE tmp
SET capital_type_id = capital_type.capital_type_id
FROM capital_type
WHERE tmp.capital = capital_type.type
```

but this ends up setting the column capital to null, however, this worked:

```
UPDATE tmp
SET capital_type_id = capital_type.capital_type_id
FROM capital_type
WHERE capital_type.type = capital;
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this without writing to the column?

Thanks!

Edit: accidentally wrote `cities` instead of `tmp`, just fixed it

Comment: To question **add** the definition for the table `tmp`?

Comment: A `WHERE` clause **never** updates a table. It controls which rows an `UPDATE` will affect, but the `WHERE` doesn't do any updating at all. Also, when you're asking about why a table named `tmp` isn't being updated as you expect, we need to see table `tmp`'s definition in your question. Sample data and what you expect that data to look like after the UPDATE would also be helpful.

Comment: Hey my bad I accidentally pasted `cities` when I meant to paste `tmp`, just fixed it thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Your first statement is better and should work well. It cannot modify `capital`.